# I’m having problems attempting to get the debugPrintfEXT working in the shaders

Tags: c++, shader, game-engine, vulkan, compute-shader

It seems like I got partly working, but every time it tries to log I get this message:

Validation Layer: Validation Warning: [ UNASSIGNED-DEBUG-PRINTF ] Object 0: handle = 0x19d6337ae88, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_DEVICE; | MessageID = 0x92394c89 | WARNING - Debug Printf message was truncated, likely due to a buffer size that was too small for the message

I'm only doing a one char test log right now untill I get it working so it shouldn't have be a problem. I've also got #extension GL_EXT_debug_printf : enable enabled in the shader.

I've gotten the debugger setting set to:

```
VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT DebugInfo = {};
DebugInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSENGER_CREATE_INFO_EXT;
DebugInfo.messageSeverity = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_VERBOSE_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_WARNING_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_ERROR_BIT_EXT;|
DebugInfo.messageType = VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_GENERAL_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_VALIDATION_BIT_EXT | VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_BIT_EXT;|
DebugInfo.pfnUserCallback = DebugCallBack;
```

Start up validation info:

```
    DeviceExtensions.emplace_back(VK_KHR_SHADER_NON_SEMANTIC_INFO_EXTENSION_NAME);

    VkValidationFeatureEnableEXT enabled[] = { VK_VALIDATION_FEATURE_ENABLE_DEBUG_PRINTF_EXT };
    VkValidationFeatureDisableEXT disabled[] = {
    VK_VALIDATION_FEATURE_DISABLE_THREAD_SAFETY_EXT, VK_VALIDATION_FEATURE_DISABLE_API_PARAMETERS_EXT,
        VK_VALIDATION_FEATURE_DISABLE_OBJECT_LIFETIMES_EXT, VK_VALIDATION_FEATURE_DISABLE_CORE_CHECKS_EXT };
    std::vector<const char*> ExtensionList = getRequiredExtensions();
    VkInstanceCreateInfo VulkanCreateInfo = {};
    VulkanCreateInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_INSTANCE_CREATE_INFO;
    VulkanCreateInfo.pApplicationInfo = &VulkanInfo;
    VulkanCreateInfo.enabledExtensionCount = static_cast<uint32_t>(ExtensionList.size());
    VulkanCreateInfo.ppEnabledExtensionNames = ExtensionList.data();

#ifdef NDEBUG
    VulkanCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = 0;
    VulkanCreateInfo.pNext = nullptr;
#else
    VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT DebugInfo;
    VulkanDebug.CreateDebugMessengerInfo(DebugInfo);

    VkValidationFeaturesEXT ValidationFeatures{};
    ValidationFeatures.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_VALIDATION_FEATURES_EXT;
    ValidationFeatures.disabledValidationFeatureCount = 4;
    ValidationFeatures.enabledValidationFeatureCount = 1;
    ValidationFeatures.pEnabledValidationFeatures = enabled;
    ValidationFeatures.pDisabledValidationFeatures = disabled;
    ValidationFeatures.pNext = (VkDebugUtilsMessengerCreateInfoEXT*)&DebugInfo;

    VulkanCreateInfo.enabledLayerCount = static_cast<unsigned int>(ValidationLayers.size());
    VulkanCreateInfo.ppEnabledLayerNames = ValidationLayers.data();
    VulkanCreateInfo.pNext = &ValidationFeatures;
```

The vk_layer_settings:

```
khronos_validation.debug_action = VK_DBG_LAYER_ACTION_LOG_MSG
khronos_validation.report_flags = error,warn,perf
khronos_validation.log_filename = stdout
khronos_validation.printf_buffer_size = 1024
khronos_validation.printf_verbose = true
```

This is the compute shader that I've attempting to log from and debug.
It's supposed to do bone animation, but been having some problems with it which lead me to find out about the shader logger.

```
#version 460
#extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable
#extension GL_EXT_nonuniform_qualifier : enable
#extension GL_EXT_scalar_block_layout : enable
#extension GL_EXT_debug_printf : enable

#include "Lighting.glsl"

struct Vertex
{
  vec3 Position;
    float     Padding1;
    vec3 Normal;
    float     Padding2;
    vec2 TexureCoord;
    vec2 Padding3;
    vec3 Tangant;
    float     Padding4;
    vec3 BiTangant;
    float     Padding5;
    vec4 Color;
    ivec4 BoneID ;
    vec4 BoneWeights;
 };

layout(binding = 0, scalar) buffer Vertices
{
  Vertex v[];
}
vertices;

layout(binding = 2) uniform UniformBufferObject {
    mat4 viewInverse;
    mat4 projInverse;
    mat4 model;
    mat4 view;
    mat4 proj;
    DirectionalLight dlight;
    vec3 viewPos;
    PointLight plight;
    float vertexSize;
    mat4 PVM;
    mat4 BoneTransform[100];
    float timer;
} ubo;
layout(binding = 5) buffer Transform { mat4 Transform; } MeshTransform[];


layout(push_constant) uniform MeshInfo
{
    uint MeshID;
    uint ModelID;
    uint MaterialID;
} Mesh;

void main()
{

    debugPrintfEXT("H");
  Vertex v0 = vertices.v[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x];

  mat4 BoneTransform = mat4(1.0f);
  BoneTransform =  ubo.BoneTransform[v0.BoneID[0]] * v0.BoneWeights[0];
  BoneTransform += ubo.BoneTransform[v0.BoneID[1]] * v0.BoneWeights[1];
  BoneTransform += ubo.BoneTransform[v0.BoneID[2]] * v0.BoneWeights[2];
  BoneTransform += ubo.BoneTransform[v0.BoneID[3]] * v0.BoneWeights[3];
  vec4 BonePosition = BoneTransform * vec4(v0.Position, 1.0);

  v0.Position = vec3(ubo.model * MeshTransform[0].Transform * BonePosition);
  v0.Normal = normalize(transpose(inverse(mat3(ubo.model * MeshTransform[0].Transform * BoneTransform))) * v0.Normal);
    v0.Color = vec4(v0.BoneID.xyz, 1.0f);
  vertices.v[gl_GlobalInvocationID.x] = v0;
}
```

Was there something I missed?

Also made a bare bones sample and still getting the same message:

Okay, I made use a basic vulkan templete using vulkantutorial and put in in the shader printf settings and still got the same error.

https://github.com/ThomasDHZ/VulkanShaderLoggerTest

https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Drawing_a_triangle/Swap_chain_recreation

Answer (score 0):

You print for every compute shader invocation with a high level of verbosity. This is most probably to much text for the default buffer size of 1024.
So you need to lower the printf invocations in your shader and also want to lower the verbosity of the messages to e.g. only `VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_INFO_BIT_EXT` instead of  `VK_DEBUG_UTILS_MESSAGE_SEVERITY_VERBOSE_BIT_EXT`.